# When is RTCPeerConnection's ontrack event triggered?

Tags: webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

The reasons I'm confused are:

1. When my media stream is detected: My camera or microphone permission is allowed.
2. When an offer is set in my local SDP using setLocalDescription
3. When receiving the other party's answer and registering as Remote SDP using setRemoteDescription

The second question is
Is the stream received through event.streams[0] the other party's stream or my stream?

I've read the MDN documentation, but it's an unfamiliar concept and I don't quite understand it.

Comment: You list 3 list items there. Are you saying that you see the onTrack event getting called at those 3 times? Or are you asking which of those times the onTrack event should be called?

Comment: I wonder what time the track event is called.